# send message from gear to phone error tizen

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables

hi guys i'm trying to send a message from gear to android phone i used the hello message sample provided by tizen but the fetch button is not doing anything
i also tried hello accessory sample and it's working without any error but no message is being shown on my android
what could be wrong ?
also i'm trying to send a message because i want to send heart rate data from gear to phone is this the right way to do this ?
please help me i've stuck with this problem for almost a month
Modify message

Comment: You need to give us (at least) brief codes to be reviewed